# Adding extra column and rearranging column values using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can I write pandas codes to add an extra column to a pandas data frame and then rearrange some column values as below:

Original data frame (Table 1):

```
ID  Type    Order
S171    UXT15   1
S171    MMU18   2
S171    SXR13   3
S171    UTX16   4
S172    SXR13   1
S172    UTX16   2
S173    UTX16   1
S173    SXR13   2
```

I want to convert the above data frame (Table 1) to Table 2 like so:

```
ID  Type    Nickname    Order
S171    UXT15   R1  1
S171    MMU18   R2  2
S171    SXR13   R3  3
S171    UTX16   R4  4
S172    SXR13   R1  1
S172    UTX16   R2  2
S173    UTX16   R2  1
S173    SXR13   R1  2
```

Table 2 has an extra column 'Nickname' according to uniqueness of 'ID' column and 'Order' column

Table 2 is then converted to the final output as follows:

```
S171    R1R2R3R4
S172    R1R2
S173    R2R1
```

That is each row of  unique 'ID' column and the 'Nicknames' matching it are arranged in sequence.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC first you can create new column combining `Order` and `Type` columns. Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html), cast by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `int` and then to `str`. Last you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) `join`:

```
df['pairs'] =  df['Order'].astype(str) + df['Type']

df['Nickname'] = 'R' + df.groupby('ID')['pairs'].rank(method='dense').astype(int).astype(str)
print df
     ID   Type  Order   pairs Nickname
0  S171  UXT15      1  1UXT15       R1
1  S171  MMU18      2  2MMU18       R2
2  S171  SXR13      3  3SXR13       R3
3  S171  UTX16      4  4UTX16       R4
4  S172  SXR13      1  1SXR13       R1
5  S172  UTX16      2  2UTX16       R2
6  S173  UTX16      1  1UTX16       R1
7  S173  SXR13      2  2SXR13       R2

print df.groupby('ID')['Nickname'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
     ID  Nickname
0  S171  R1R2R3R4
1  S172      R1R2
2  S173      R1R2
```

EDIT by comment:

If you aggregate only column `Type`, last rows are swapped, but first rows are reorder, because `rank` lexsorted:

```
df['Nickname'] = 'R' + df.groupby('ID')['Type'].rank(method='dense').astype(int).astype(str)
print df
     ID   Type  Order Nickname
0  S171  UXT15      1       R4
1  S171  MMU18      2       R1
2  S171  SXR13      3       R2
3  S171  UTX16      4       R3
4  S172  SXR13      1       R1
5  S172  UTX16      2       R2
6  S173  UTX16      1       R2
7  S173  SXR13      2       R1

print df.groupby('ID')['Nickname'].apply(''.join).reset_index()
     ID  Nickname
0  S171  R4R1R2R3
1  S172      R1R2
2  S173      R2R1
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the output the OP is requesting.  (I don't get how the OP's Nickname column works, so I can't be any help there.)

Comment: Yes, I see it. Last 2 rows are swapped.